# Create Array of data for Collection Type

Tags: php, forms, symfony, model-view-controller, fosuserbundle

I am working on a Symfony based project, and I'm using FosUserBundle.

I have a problem, when trying to render a `CollectionType:Class`, well, I would like to let my users filling fields with content that I don't already have in my database.

From what I've read in Symfony documentation, in order to make that type work, it is necessary to have a an array of data Pre Set as entry.

So my question is, "Is there, anyway for me to create an array of data and pass it to my field to make it appear ?"

My WorkshopType :

```
class WorkshopType extends AbstractType implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add( 'title', TextType::class, array('label'=>"Titre"))
            ->add( 'goal', TextareaType::class, array('label'=>"But"))
            ->add( 'theme', TextType::class, array('label'=>"Theme"))
            ->add( 'target', TextType::class, array('label'=>"Cible"))
            ->add( 'summary', TextareaType::class, array('label'=>"Résumé"))
            ->add('maxParticipants', NumberType::class, array('label'=>"Nombre de Participants Maximum", 'data' => 0))
            ->add('moderatorsNumber', NumberType::class, array('label'=>"Nombre de Modérateurs",'data' => 0))
            ->add('materials', CollectionType::class, [
                 //'label' => 'Matériaux',
                 'entry_type' => TextType::class,
                'entry_options'  => array(
                    'attr'      => array('class' => 'material-box')
                ),
                'prototype' => true,
                 'allow_add' => true,
                 'allow_delete' => true,
             ])
            ->add( 'link', UrlType::class, array('label'=>"Lien"))
            ->add('video', FileType::class, array('label'=>"Ajouter une vidéo", "data_class" => null))
            ->add('image', FileType::class, array('label'=>"Ajouter une image", "data_class" => null))
            ->add('document', FileType::class, array('label'=>"Ajouter un document", "data_class" => null))
            ->add('tags', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Tag::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'empty_data' => 'Aucun',
                'label' => 'Ajouter des affinités',
            ])
            ->add('duration', TimeType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Durée',
                'input'  => 'timestamp',
                'widget' => 'choice',
            ))
            ->add('preparationTime', TimeType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Temps de préparation',
                'input'  => 'timestamp',
                'widget' => 'choice',
            ))
        ;

        // It's here you have to make changes if you want to change the duration render type
        $builder
            ->get('duration')->addModelTransformer(new SecondDurationDataTransformer());
        $builder
            ->get('preparationTime')->addModelTransformer(new SecondDurationDataTransformer());
        $builder
            ->get('document')->addModelTransformer(new MediaTransformer(
                "ApiBundle\Entity\Workshop",
                $options['entityId'],
                $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager'),
                $this->container->get('bnpp.api.file_manager.local'),
                "document",
                "ApiBundle\Entity\Document"));
        $builder
            ->get('image')->addModelTransformer(new MediaTransformer(
                "ApiBundle\Entity\Workshop",
                $options['entityId'],
                $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager'),
                $this->container->get('bnpp.api.file_manager.local'),
                "image",
                "ApiBundle\Entity\Image"));
        $builder
            ->get('video')->addModelTransformer(new MediaTransformer(
                "ApiBundle\Entity\Workshop",
                $options['entityId'],
                $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager'),
                $this->container->get('bnpp.api.file_manager.local'),
                "video",
                "ApiBundle\Entity\Video"));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Workshop::class,
            'required' => false,
            "entityId" => null,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'apibundle_workshop';
    }


}
```

Thank you all,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the array as default value like that :

`'choices' => $yourArray,`